# SQL to select row with added_date and updated_date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select a row order by `added_date` or if row is updated then order by `updated_date`.

Default the updated date is `Null`.

For the above table date given in (`dd-mm-yy`).

For the below table the first row is added at 2 feb and second is added at 1 feb so by using ,

```
select * from tablename order by added_date desc;
```

I get the latest row, but if any row is updated then this updated row becomes latest row.

For second row, row added at 1st feb but it's updated at 3rd feb so its becomes latest row.

How can I get the record with added and updated date ??

```
    id   title    name   added_date   updated_date
     1   asd      rff     02-02-2013    NULL
     2   fsfs     rwr     01-02-2013    03-02-2012
     3   ddd      wwrr    30-01-2013    04-02-2013
```

Edit:using MYSQL

Comment: @marc_s:using Mysql ,but need only query to get records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify which RDBMS you use. For Oracle you can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY NVL(updated_date,added_date) DESC;
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY ISNULL(updated_date,added_date) DESC
```

MySQL:

```
select * from tablename order by ifnull(updated_date,added_date) desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

try using `COALESCE`

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    tablename 
ORDER   BY COALESCE(updated_date, added_date) DESC
```

- [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

From Docs:

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE updated_date 
        WHEN NULL THEN added_date 
        ELSE updated_date
         END 
    desc
```